# Why am I not able to change the shell with the chsh command?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command-line

I learned a new command, at least I thought, because this command : `chsh`, does not behave like described.

It was described to work like this:

1. `cat /etc/shells` to know, which shells are installed,so you can choose among them.
2. do `echo $SHELL` to know, which shell you are using.
3. choose one of the shells and type `chsh -s /path/to/shell`
4. enter password and verify with `echo $SHELL`, that you are in a new shell.

I have done this and I got no error message when entering the password, but I was still in the same shell.

```
% echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
% cat /etc/shells
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
% chsh -s /bin/sh
Password: 
% echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Comment: You have to logout and login again first.

Comment: [text should be posted as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: I edited my post, deleted the image and pasted the text instead, but the image  came back over night.

Comment: @sharkant It looks like someone had an edit in a review queue and it got approved, which edited your post after the fact. I thought the SE edit system wouldn't overwrite a new edit with an old one, but heh, who knows?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Log out and log in again.

The `chsh` command will update the `/etc/passwd` file, but it does not change the *current* shell nor the value of the `$SHELL` variable in the current shell (it has no way of doing that). This is the reason you need to log in again; you have to start a new login session for a change to take effect.

Comment: I do not understand what a login shell is and how I know if I am in a login shell or some kind of not login shell. How do I start a new login session?

Comment: @sharkant The point is that the information that you changed in the `/etc/passwd` is not read until you log in next time. You will have to log out completely, and log in again for the change to take effect. If you fail in doing this, then rebooting the machine will also work.

Comment: I think I understand you this time: so the chsh -s /path/to/shell command does not change immediately the shell i am in, but it changes an entry inside /etc/passwd which will take effect when I start the shell?

Comment: @sharkant That's exactly the way it works! I'm happy I finally understood you misconception. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Using **usermod** utility command worked in my case. Running on the ubuntu 18.04.

1. First, check current value

`grep nameofuser /etc/passwd`

2. change it

`sudo usermod --shell /bin/bash nameofuser`

3. Verify it

`grep nameofuser /etc/passwd`

Comment: Thaaaaaaaank you